# How to manage Binary calculation and aggregation with Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am performing some calculations on binary samples collected into an Oracle 11g database.

Samples collections are represented by a `raw(4000)` datatype.

I need to perform very basic operations such as:

- Set or reset the `nth` bit
- `AND` or `OR` on the `nth` bit
- `AND` or `OR` two collections
- Aggregate the collections

I started playing with `BITAND(number)` and `BITOR(number)`, but this is limited due to number limitations: 2 power 418.

I started looking at some specific packages (as in Oracle 8) but could not find them on my server.

Can someone provide me with some hints and recommendations to run these calculations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Oracle's UTL_RAW package for raw data manipulation:
[UTL_RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_raw.htm#i996746)

You may need to have your DBA install it and grant you access to it, but it IS shipped with your database server.

Comment: Yes, this package is the one I need, and it is installed by default: select distinct object_name from dba_objects where object_type = 'PACKAGE' and object_name like 'UTL%'; shows it. Using a function requires to prefix it, such as: UTL_RAW.BIT_OR( raw, raw). Thanks!